# How to hide columns in task list?

Tags: list

I created a task list but I want to hide the columns 'Related Content' and 'Outcome' - how do I do this? I am using Sharepoint 2010 and I am a site owner. Also, what are these columns for?

Answer (score 1):

go to list settings, press on Tasks content type, and from what content type setting you are able to change the visibility of the columns, just press on column you need to hide and select that option and save.
Creating task list using tasks list template creates all related columns for general usage, so if you don't need some columns, you could just remove them of hide. Or you could create custom content type with columns you want to have, and add it to the list (and remove default content types from it).

Answer (score 0):

Also a good solution can be creating a new view for this task list and making it default.

With a view you can filter wich fields you want to show and wich not. Also can use the hidden column to filter the results of this view.

Answer (score 0):

1. Select the content type where these columns exists.
2. Select the metadata (column) you want to hide.
3. In "Column Settings" Category, there will be three options i.e.
   Required, Optional and Hidden. Select "Hidden" and press "OK" to
   hide the field.
4. Now when we go back to the new item form, the field does not show
   up.
5. With this, we could use this solution to decide what information we
   need users to input and what information we need to display in the
   default list forms provided in SharePoint.